# How to pass a css param to main.gsp layout

Tags: grails

I have main.gsp in my layouts.  Several other layouts each apply the main layout, but each of the layouts has a different background for the page (borders, background image, width, etc).

In my main.gsp I have the css style defined as:

```
<div class="container <g:pageProperty name="page.containerCss"/>">
```

and in my nested gsps I'm passing up the css to use in the main container:

```
<g:applyLayout name="main">
...
<body>
<content tag="containerCss">myCustomCssStyle</content>
```

Or another nested layout might use:

```
 <content tag="containerCss">aDifferentStyle</content>
```

Is there a better way to do this?  The only variable in the main.gsp is this one css property, so I don't think creating 5 different versions of main.gsp is a DRY option.

Comment: It depends. How many pages with every layout do you have? How many pages uses default layout?

Comment: There are about 20 pages that use main as the parent.  Of those there are 5 unique css classes that need to be passed to main.  All of the rest of the site are derived from the 20, so they aren't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could set a variable with scope on request in your nested gsp´s like

```
 <g:set var="containerCss" value="aDifferentStyle" scope="request" />
```

and in your main.gsp you can use it like :

```
<div class="container ${containerCss}">
```

i did not test it but it should work, have fun !

edit: please let me know if it did not work